# Wiring Method Improper or simply Unsafe?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Location; Single Family Residence, Los Angeles California.
Please share your comments and repairs recommendation; Although I am not an electrical contractor or an electrical repair person, however, I am concerned about my friend' s house' s wiring method to supply 30A Dryer at the garage, via Flexible Metal Conduit. I am assuming this was done several years ago, however, I am concerned that wiring' s method, via Flex. Metal Conduit is unsafe for this situation and should have been done differently, both in selection of the conduit' s type and access to the service panel?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the inside of the receptacle box for the dryer please?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it looks ugly. Definitely not a professional installation, but there doesn't seem to be a code violation or hazard based on your pictures.

If it was done recently, then it's not to code because the installer put in a NEMA 10-30R receptacle (3-prong) instead of the required modern NEMA 14-30R (4-prong).

You can simply leave it as is and use it. Just make sure the copper bonding strap remains in place on whatever dryer you put there. They come with it installed by default.

Comment: Yeah, that receptacle was outlawed in 1996. But in all other respects, the hillbillies got lucky and it appears to comply with Code.  The REAL crime against good design is "finishing" the walls in *what's obviously a utility space*. This utterly fails to make the space more attractive, so mission fail there, and makes it impossible to ... run... utilities.  Except where required for fire-stopping, it should have been left open joists, where the FMC tucked into those joists would not have offended the eye in any way whatsoever.

Comment: I totally agree. Terrible patch job.

Comment: Yeah, fill permitting, they could slink a bare 10AWG up the conduit, land it in the panel, swap the receptacle to NEMA 14, and roll that way, for that matter

Comment: Yeah that would be best. It's hard to tell from the pic but it looks like 3/4 flex. But I just did the calculation and even if it's 1/2", 4 x #10 AWG THHN wires is only 28% fill.